# Install Ubuntu 16.04 on a Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: server, system-installation, 16.04, reboot, raspberrypi

atm i am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Raspbery Pi 2. I am using the official Image [from here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi).
For the installation i use the software win32diskimager. When the installation process is finished, i put my sd card into my raspberry and every time it boots normally and i can do whatever i want. But when i try to reboot the system, it is shutting down, but cant boot anymore.
I tried to update or upgrade, but nothing helps. The only thing that helps sometimes is to:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/mmcblk0
```

then i type

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

but still in the fdisk menu. When i then try to reboot, it can reboot and works normally as long as i dont upgrade or dist-upgrade the raspberry.
Even the official installation instructions cant help me.

Do you have any ideas what i can do, to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to comment, but you may consider this as such.

I have had a similar problem before and I solved it by getting a power supply with higher amperage. Usually you are told not to go above one amp, but if you have the device running in a cool environment or have small aftermarket heatsinks on it, it shouldn't be a problem, also because the new Pi's have built in voltage regulators.

**TL;DR:** try to find a power supply or phone charger that outputs 1.5A, 5V or more up to 2A.

Comment: I have also experimented with getting a power supply with higher amperage by using a larger power supply with the same voltage to replace a burned out adapter that was connected to speakers. This resulted in a low pitched drumming noise from the speakers and no sound otherwise. When I replaced the adapter with an adapter that had exactly the same specs as the original adapter, the speakers worked fine . So my experience is that increasing the amperage doesn't always produce hoped for results.

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but unfortunately i am using already a 5V and 2A power supply :/.